# Output is not coming after a certain point of value

Tags: c

The code written below  converts from decimal to binary. The code gives the right output till 1009. After that onwards it gives wrong output. Why so?
int is guaranteed to be able to store, at the very least, values that lie within the range of -32767 and 32767.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int remainder, n = 0;
  long binary = 0;
  int i = 1;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  while (n != 0) 
  {
    remainder = n % 2;

    binary = binary + remainder * i;
    i = i * 10;

    n = n / 2;
  }

  printf("%ld", binary);  // Be sure to use "%ld" with `long`.
  return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
INPUT:  1100
OUTPUT: 1411066508
```

Comment: Because the "binary" number you are building is actually a decimal number, and overflows `int`. Input `1023` gives the decimal `1111111111` which fits a 32-bit `int` but with `2047` the value `11111111111` does not.

Comment: Conversion from decimal to binary doesn't do anything. Your code stores a binary representation of a decimal number as a decimal.

Comment: In fact `1023` is the highest number which work with 32-bit `int`. The next number `1024` is binary `10000000000` but those digits, as a decimal number, don't fit a 32-bit `int` or even `unsigned int`.

Comment: If code uses `i=i*8;` and `printf("%o",binary);`, code can go to 2000.

Comment: @chux good idea using octal but of course OP should either output bit by bit, or build a digit *string*.

Comment: If it's not obvious from the other comments and answers, storing a "binary" number in a variable of type `int`, and trying to convert it to decimal as another `int`, is a rather poor (I would say plainly wrong) way of doing it.  You should enter your binary number into, and convert from, a string, instead.

Comment: @WeatherVane what is a 32 bit int vs 64 bit int

Comment: @WeatherVane what is the range of a 32 bit int ?

Comment: @SaumyojitDas the range of a 32-bit `int` is given in `limits.h` as `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @stevesummit how to implement string concept in this program . Can u write the code .

Comment: Your code gives me `1411066419` from `1099`

Comment: Is `long` 64-bit on your system? To get a better range, both `binary` and `i` should be 64-bit, note too that `printf("%d",binary);` is incorrect. It should be `printf("%ld",binary);`

Comment: @WeatherVane  64 bit sytem means what WINDOWS 64 bit or compiler has to be 64 bit. **My windows 10 is 64 bit and my dev c compiler is TDM-GCC4.9.2 64 bit release** . plzz make a change to the above code so that i works for every decimal no.

Comment: No, it means the size of the variable. On my system `long int` is 32 bits and `long long int` is 64 bits, and `int64_t` is 64 bits on every system. But changing the code to use 64-bit variables still won't work for *every* decimal number. It will only raise the upper limit, to `524287` for `long long int` and to `1048575` for `unsigned long long int`. Moreover, as commented, it is better to change your approach to the problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane  stevesummit  said that You should enter your binary number into, and convert from, a string, instead. what is this mean? should i make long binary to string binary .please edify .what should be the code then.

Comment: how can i remove the question ban tag . The rules are telling to improve the previously asked  questions of mine but  i dont know where to improve . Please help . i cant wait another 6 months

Answer (score 1):

> After that onwards it gives wrong output. Why so?

Either of the 2 below **overflowed**.  Values well exceeded 32767.

```
binary=binary+remainder*i;
i=i*10;
```

Try this code to demonstrate.

```
printf("before: binary %ld, remainder %d, i  %d\n", binary, remainder, i);
binary=binary+remainder*i;
i=i*10;
printf("after:  binary %ld, remainder %d, i  %d\n", binary, remainder, i);
```

Note that once signed integer overflow occurs, that is *undefined behavior* and anything may happen.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int remainder, n = 0;
  long int binary = 0;
  int i = 1;
  n = 1010;
  while (n != 0) {
    remainder = n % 2;
    printf("before: binary %10ld, remainder %d, i  %10d\n", binary, remainder, i);
    binary = binary + remainder * i;
    i = i * 10;
    printf("after:  binary %10ld, remainder %d, i  %10d\n", binary, remainder, i);
    n = n / 2;
  }
  printf("%ld", binary);  // Be sure to use "%ld" with `long`.
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
before: binary          0, remainder 0, i           1
after:  binary          0, remainder 0, i          10
before: binary          0, remainder 1, i          10
after:  binary         10, remainder 1, i         100
before: binary         10, remainder 0, i         100
after:  binary         10, remainder 0, i        1000
before: binary         10, remainder 0, i        1000
after:  binary         10, remainder 0, i       10000
before: binary         10, remainder 1, i       10000
after:  binary      10010, remainder 1, i      100000
before: binary      10010, remainder 1, i      100000
after:  binary     110010, remainder 1, i     1000000
before: binary     110010, remainder 1, i     1000000
after:  binary    1110010, remainder 1, i    10000000
before: binary    1110010, remainder 1, i    10000000
after:  binary   11110010, remainder 1, i   100000000
before: binary   11110010, remainder 1, i   100000000
after:  binary  111110010, remainder 1, i  1000000000
before: binary  111110010, remainder 1, i  1000000000
after:  binary 1111110010, remainder 1, i  1410065408
1111110010
```

For `i` to become 10,000,000,000, its value would exceed `INT_MAX`.